# Proving that if $A^*A + B^*B = 0$, then $A = B = 0$ for linear operators $A, B$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Is this proof valid?

$A^*A + B^*B = 0$ implies $A^*A = -B^*B$. But, for any linear operator $A$, we have $xA^*Ax \ge 0$. Since $xA^*Ax = - xB^*Bx$, $- xB^*Bx \ge 0$, so $xB^*Bx \le 0$. But also, $xB^*Bx \ge 0$. Therefore $B^*B = 0$, so $B = 0$. By the same argument, $A = 0$.

The main steps I'm uncertain about are:

- is $A^*A$ positive definite for any linear operator $A$?
- does $A^*A = 0$ imply $A = 0$?

Comment: $\langle A^*Ax,x\rangle=\langle Ax,Ax\rangle\ge 0.$ Thus $Ax=0,$ hence $A=0.$

Comment: For any vector $x$ we have $0=(x, (A^*A+B^*B)x)=$ $(x,A^*Ax)+(x,B^*Bx)=$ $(Ax,Ax)+(Bx,Bx)=$ $\|Ax\|^2+\|Bx\|^2,$  implying $\|Ax\|=\|Bx\|=0.$ And for your last Q, consider the case $A^*A+B^*B=0=B.$